# Accessing requested values after url rewrite - PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an issue after rewrite url i can't able to access value using $_REQUEST, so i use

```
$url = explode("/",($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
$cnturl=count($url);
```

is there is another way to get the requested value... because i dont want to make changes all over pages. My url be like ***sample/value***

Also I have to add the website before includeing/calling any css or js files

like

before

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
```

after

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="www.website.com/css/custom.css" />
```

My .htaccess file is:

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /company\.php\?comp=([^&\s]+)\s
RewriteRule ^ /company/%2/? [L,R=301]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Thanks for support...

Comment: Are you doing a form POST?

Comment: No i simply pass value thru url

Comment: If you want a subfolder-like url on your application, you should use absolute urls (e.g. `http://website.com/css/style.css` ) or more specific relative urls (e.g. `/css/style.css` ) or even set a `<base href="">`

Comment: What's the full URL are you entering in browser to test this?

Answer (score 0):

You tried with the QSA param appended?

```
RewriteRule ^ /company/%2/? [L,R=301,QSA]
```